# Relaxing Constraints for a data table adapter

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms, tableadapter

I'm trying to relax my constraints while using a data table adapter, but I'm getting a **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error. It happens on the line that says ds.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;

Generally, I would like to know how to keep a dataTable from enforcing constraints.

```
ubsmysDataSetTableAdapters.FormSaveDataTableAdapter ta = new ubsmysDataSetTableAdapters.FormSaveDataTableAdapter();

myDataSet.FormSaveDataDataTable ds = new myDataSet.FormSaveDataDataTable();

ds.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;

if (isAdmin) ds = ta.GetByUserIdForAdminUser(userId);
else ds = ta.GetByUserId(userId);
ds.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
```

I'm fairly new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if ds is already a DataSet why do you call ds.DataSet ? do some debug anyway, is ds null or ds.DataSet null?

Comment: That's a good question. The intellisense is telling me that is where the property for EnforceConstraints is. Let me try it without that.

Comment: It seems like ds is not a data set, but a data table... hmm

Comment: No, just a table adapter to grab data from a table. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Ok, see my heavily edited answer below. Let me know if you follow the code or have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, you may have to adjust the text you see in blue to be a perfect match to what yours are, but you should be able to get the idea:

**Use the Fill method to get your data:**

```
ubsmysDataSet ds = new ubsmysDataSet();

ubsmysDataSet.FormSaveDataDataTable dt = new ubsmysDataSet.FormSaveDataDataTable();

ds.Tables.Add(dt);

ds.EnforceConstraints = false;

ubsmysDataSetTableAdapters.FormSaveDataTableAdapter ta = new ubsmysDataSetTableAdapters.FormSaveDataTableAdapter();

if (isAdmin)
{

}
else
{
    ta.FillByUserId(dt,130559)
}

ds.EnforceConstraints = true;
```

See the added line above.

Comment: This looks hopeful. Let me try this.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. The constraints are still enforced for dt, even though we turned them off for ds and added dt to ds.Tables

Comment: You could just go to the dataset itself and turn off constraints, but I don't know what restrictions you are working around. (Let me see if I can adjust the code if that's not an option).

Comment: I tried that too and seemed to have the exact same issues with it. Let me try it again just to see.

Comment: If that doesn't work you can try to add the line I just added in my answer, and see if that works.

Comment: Same result, unfortunately :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4337/discussion-between-kreepn-and-maxx)

Answer (score 0):

```
new myDataSet.FormSaveDataDataTable();
```

is returning `null`, thus `ds` will be `null` when you try to `ds.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;`.

Something feels wrong here, but since you have not posted all code, we cannot fully evaluate.

Comment: Wouldn't it be null if it was a new dataset? If I fill it first and try to set EnforceConstraints to false, it tells me that I have a constraints issue.

Comment: I'm pointing your **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error. And a new dataset is different from a null dataset

Comment: Neither am I. Like I said, you gave us too little. Little is what you get, I guess. We cannot help any further. Maybe if you post the code in `FormSaveDataDataTable`?

Comment: It's code generated by the table adapter. Nothing out of the ordinary. Does a table adapter initially return null when created?

Comment: It seems like what I'm actually trying to set is the data table which is null until it is set by the GetByUserId method. This returns a data table, however, not a dataset. How can I release the constraints on the data set for this datatable?